# How PWA - Serviceworker (React) works?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a question about how to shape PWA applications. I understand that Serviceworker help web apps to be like an application offering offline features and more.

So, can I create one for mobile and another one for the PC web browser to provide it with the same domain by recognizing types of hardware - how typical website works? Or, if I want to create PWA, then it must be dedicated to mobile service only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create separate web apps for mobile & desktop.

Just create a responsive web app and make it progressive by adding the manifest & service worker.

It isn't specific to mobile or desktop.
It's a website after all.
You open it in any supported browser, it will work.
You can either use it as a conventional website or a PWA (If the browser supports)